# Connect between WSO2 ESB and AM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-as, wso2-esb

I wanted to connect WSO2 ESB's Health Care Proxy Sample to API Manager.
But i failed to connect two products.

---

1. I installed 3 WSO2 product(APIM, ESB and AS) in one local machine(Windows 7 64bit, java7) and gave different offset per product (APIM is 2, AS is 1 and ESB is 0).

---

2. I run AS Server and uploaded 3 aar file (geows-SNAPSHOT.aar, hcfacilitylocator-SNAPSHOT.aar, hcinformationservice-SNAPSHOT.aar) on AS.
   (Downloaded from http://wso2.com/files/Service_Integration_Artifacts.zip)

---

3. I run ESB Server and uploaded 1 car file (Service_Integration_CApp_1.0.0.car) on ESB.
   (Downloaded from http://wso2.com/files/Service_Integration_Artifacts.zip)

---

4.1 When i try using POSTMAN of chrome browser, it succeed like following.

URL is

```
http://localhost:8280/services/HCCProxyService
```

Method is

```
GET
```

I added two Header

```
SOAPAction

SOAPMessage
```

SOAPAction's value is 
    getHealthcareCenterInfo

SOAPMessage's value is `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:heal="http://healthcare.wso2"><soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><heal:getHealthcareCenterInfo><!--Optional:--><heal:longitude>3</heal:longitude><!--Optional:--><heal:latitude>4</heal:latitude></heal:getHealthcareCenterInfo></soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>`

I got following response

```
<ns:getHCCenterInfoResponse 
xmlns:ns="http://healthcare.wso2">
<ns:return 
    xmlns:ax2460="http://healthcare.wso2/xsd" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax2460:HCInfo">
    <ax2460:address>2285 North Central Avenue</ax2460:address>
    <ax2460:approxDistance>1.5</ax2460:approxDistance>
    <ax2460:city>Kissimmee,  FL</ax2460:city>
    <ax2460:hcCenterName>QKissimmee CBOC</ax2460:hcCenterName>
    <ax2460:phone>407-518-5004</ax2460:phone>
</ns:return>
```

---

5. I added following config on axis2.xml file

   `<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>`

and run AM Server and added this service on AM's publisher site through following step.
5.1 In design step
Context name is

`test`

URL Pattern is
`test`

selected two method is

`GET`, `OPTIONS`

---

5.2 In Implementation step

Endpoint type is

`WSDL Endpoint`

Production WSDL is

`http://localhost:8280/services/HCCProxyService?wsdl`

Service is

`HCCProxyService`

Port is

`HCCProxyServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint`

---

5.3 In Manage step

Tier Availability is

`Bronze`,`Gold`,`Silver`,`Unlimited`

Transport is

`HTTP`, `HTTPS`

---

5.4 Save & Publish

---

6. I subscribed this service on AM's store site and generated accesstoken.

---

7. I try using POSTMAN of chrome browser with following settings

URL is

```
http://172.21.100.172:8282/test/1.0.0/test
```

Method is

```
GET
```

I added two Header

```
SOAPAction

SOAPMessage
```

SOAPAction's value is 
    getHealthcareCenterInfo

SOAPMessage's value is `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:heal="http://healthcare.wso2"><soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><heal:getHealthcareCenterInfo><!--Optional:--><heal:longitude>3</heal:longitude><!--Optional:--><heal:latitude>4</heal:latitude></heal:getHealthcareCenterInfo></soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>`

Authorization is

```
Bearer 9970836add803ff1184d985bbb59669
```

Content-type is

```
application/xml;charset=UTF-8
```

---

8. Finally, i just got following messages in chrome browser

   202 Accepted

ESB log is following.

```
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,691] DEBUG - wire >> "POST /services/HCCProxyService.HCCProxyServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,692] DEBUG - wire >> "Accept-Language: ko,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,692] DEBUG - wire >> "Cookie: JSESSIONID=939D5BC8522D01F309A237606C5F343F[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,692] DEBUG - wire >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,692] DEBUG - wire >> "SOAPMessage: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:heal="http://healthcare.wso2">    <soapenv:Header></soapenv:He
ader>    <soapenv:Body>       <heal:getHealthcareCenterInfo>          <!--Optional:-->          <heal:longitude>3</heal:longitude>          <!--Optional:-->          <heal:latitude>4</heal:latitude>
     </heal:getHealthcareCenterInfo>    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,692] DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Type: text/xml[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,693] DEBUG - wire >> "Accept: application/xml[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,693] DEBUG - wire >> "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,694] DEBUG - wire >> "SOAPAction: "getHealthcareCenterInfo"[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,694] DEBUG - wire >> "Host: jonghwa79lee2:8243[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,694] DEBUG - wire >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,694] DEBUG - wire >> "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,694] DEBUG - wire >> "[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,695] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 >> POST /services/HCCProxyService.HCCProxyServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint HTTP/1.1
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,695] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 >> Accept-Language: ko,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,696] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 >> Cookie: JSESSIONID=939D5BC8522D01F309A237606C5F343F
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,696] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,696] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 >> SOAPMessage: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:heal="http://healthcare.wso2">    <soapenv:
Header></soapenv:Header>    <soapenv:Body>       <heal:getHealthcareCenterInfo>          <!--Optional:-->          <heal:longitude>3</heal:longitude>          <!--Optional:-->          <heal:latitude>
4</heal:latitude>       </heal:getHealthcareCenterInfo>    </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,697] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 >> Content-Type: text/xml
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,697] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 >> Accept: application/xml
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,697] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 >> Cache-Control: no-cache
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,698] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 >> SOAPAction: "getHealthcareCenterInfo"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,698] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 >> Host: jonghwa79lee2:8243
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,698] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,698] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 >> User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,709] ERROR - RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: ?덇린移??딆? ?뚯씪???앹엯?덈떎.
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createStAXSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:196)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:55)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:118)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:107)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:82)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:68)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:411)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: ?덇린移??딆? ?뚯씪???앹엯?덈떎.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 20 more
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,731] ERROR - SequenceMediator Error while building message
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:236)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:111)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:82)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:68)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:411)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: ?덇린移??딆? ?뚯씪???앹엯?덈떎.
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createStAXSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:196)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:55)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:118)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: ?덇린移??딆? ?뚯씪???앹엯?덈떎.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 20 more
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,737] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 << HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,737] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 << Date: Wed, 11 Feb 2015 06:07:48 GMT
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,737] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 << Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,737] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,738] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-18 << Connection: Keep-Alive
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,738] DEBUG - wire << "HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,738] DEBUG - wire << "Date: Wed, 11 Feb 2015 06:07:48 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,738] DEBUG - wire << "Server: WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,739] DEBUG - wire << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,739] DEBUG - wire << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,739] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,740] DEBUG - wire << "0[\r][\n]"
[2015-02-11 15:07:48,740] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
```

---

9. **Direct call to ESB is successful, but using AM is failed. What i have to do???**
   **I want to get following response using apim (Not a 202 Accepted Message)**

I wanna following response

```
<ns:getHCCenterInfoResponse 
xmlns:ns="http://healthcare.wso2">
<ns:return 
    xmlns:ax2460="http://healthcare.wso2/xsd" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax2460:HCInfo">
    <ax2460:address>2285 North Central Avenue</ax2460:address>
    <ax2460:approxDistance>1.5</ax2460:approxDistance>
    <ax2460:city>Kissimmee,  FL</ax2460:city>
    <ax2460:hcCenterName>QKissimmee CBOC</ax2460:hcCenterName>
    <ax2460:phone>407-518-5004</ax2460:phone>
</ns:return>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. In step 5.2, i modified as following and it works!!!

5.2 In Implementation step

Endpoint type is

```
HTTP Endpoint
```

Production WSDL is

```
http://localhost:8280/services/HCCProxyService?wsdl
```